# Пользователь голосует за какой-то текст, как приложению собрать эти голоса?

Tags: клиент-сервер, ios

Добрый день! я хотел бы создать простенькое приложение для айфона, но уже возник вопрос в реализации. Скажем в приложении список статей, пользователи могут оценить каждую статью от 1 до 5, мне нужно собрать эти оценки и выставить статье общую среднюю оценку, чтобы её видели все.

Какие есть способы сбора данных - можно ли это сделать через айклауд или нужно поднимать какой-то отдельный сервер на апач? и что можно почитать на эту тему?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Да, скорее всего вам нужен некий back end (не обязательно апач, апач просто занимается обработкой запросов).

Можете посмотреть вот эту вещь [Parse](https://parse.com).

Откуда сейчас берутся статьи?

Comment: спасибо за подсказку, поизучаю!
статьи забиваются вручную.

Comment: Вам нужен какой-нибудь сервер, на котором будут храниться соответствия локальной статьи с голосами, можно к примеру отправлять на сервер id статьи + голос (+1/-1), и в приложении отправлять запрос на сервер для получения кол-ва голосов для конкретной статьи.

Но в таком случае имеет смысл и сами статьи вынести на сервер.

Comment: Да, вы правы! так и сделаю. спасибо за направление движения, я теперь знаю что такое бакэнд система и сейчас выбираю между Parse и QuickBlox(понравилась статья где они хорошо все расписали насчет своего проекта)

Answer (score 1):

относительно новый и интересный ios back-end 
[Helios](http://helios.io/)